# Referencing a member of a member in template

Tags: c++, templates

I'm using `boost::multi_index_container` and I'm trying to refer to a member of a member in a template argument, but it's unclear how to do this:

```
struct Foo {
    int unique_value;
};

struct Bar {
    Foo foo;
    double non_unique_value;
};

// I want to refer to some_value in a template argument:
multi_index_container<Bar, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
    ordered_unique< member< Foo, int, &Bar::foo::unique_value > >, // this doesn't work
    ordered_non_unique< member< Bar, double, &Bar::non_unique_value > > // this works
> >
```

How can I refer to `unique_value` in the template argument?  I understand why what I did doesn't work: I should be conveying that `Foo` is a type that is a member of `Bar` and be doing something more akin to `Bar::Foo::some_value`, but it's unclear how I can specify this.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/key_extraction.html#member

boost::multi_index_container allows this and that's how you specify the member on which you want to create an index on.

Comment: thanks, I looked it up, it specifies pointer to member variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions about this feature pop-up from time to time, since it is indeed a very logical thing to have. But unfortunately it is not part of the language.

See this thread as well [Is Pointer-to- " inner struct" member forbidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929887/is-pointer-to-inner-struct-member-forbidden)

Answer (score 1):

You could work around this with a suitable method in Bar

```
struct Bar {
    Foo foo;
    double non_unique_value;
    int get_unique_value() const { return foo.unique_value; }
};
```

and then use [const_mem_fun](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/key_extraction.html#const_mem_fun)

```
ordered_non_unique<  const_mem_fun<Bar,int,&Bar::get_unique_value> >
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using `global_fun`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a [user-defined key extractor](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/key_extraction.html#user_defined_key_extractors) that does the work.